# If $x\equiv y\text{ mod }P^j$ for all $j$, then does it imply that $x=y$ ?

Tags: ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity. Let $P$ be a prime ideal of $R$. If $x\equiv y\text{ mod }P^j$ for all $j\in\mathbb{N}$, does it imply $x=y$ ?

Comment: That's the same as asking if $\bigcap_{j=1}^{\infty} P^j=0$.

Comment: The $R=k\times k$, where $k$ is a field. There is a prime ideal $P$ in $R$ which has the property that $P^2=P$, hence $P^j=P$ for all $j$.